# How to make float navbars with JS and CSS?

Tags: javascript, css

How can I make my lower navbar to stay in the top when I scrolling down? I mean I want to hide only upper navbar? The lower navbar should take place of upper nav.

I tried to affix function:

```
$('.navbar-lower').affix({
    offset: {top: 50}
});
```

But my code doesn't work.

Here is my try on `jsFiddle`: http://jsfiddle.net/hw3gxhhf

How can I fix it?

**PS**

Also I use `jquery.bootstrap-autohidingnavbar.min.js`

```
$("div.navbar-fixed-top").autoHidingNavbar({
    "showOnBottom": false,
    "showOnUpscroll": false
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can always listen for the scroll event, and check the scrollTop value. Once you've reached the 50px threshold, you change the margin-top value:

```
window.addEventListener('scroll', function(){
    if (document.body.scrollTop >= 50) {
        $('.navbar-lower').css('margin-top','0px');
    } else {
        $('.navbar-lower').css('margin-top','50px');
    }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using the .scroll function to addClass of position:fixed; 
and z-index:10;

script-

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
var scrolled = $(window).scrollTop();
var elemTop  = $('#move').offset().top;

if (scrolled >= elemTop) {
  $('body').addClass('nav-is-fixed');
}
else {
  $('body').removeClass('nav-is-fixed');
}
});
```

css-

```
.nav-is-fixed #move {
 position: fixed;
top: 0;
z-index:10;
}
```